# Downloading file from FTP using cURL

Tags: download, ftp, curl

I'm trying to use a cURL command to download a file from an FTP server to a local drive on my computer.  I've tried

> curl "ftp://myftpsite" --user name:password -Q "CWD /users/myfolder/" -O "myfile.raw"

But it returns an error that says:

> curl: Remote file name has no length!
>   curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: myfile.raw; No data record of requested type

I've tried some other methods, but nothing seems to work.

Also, I'm not quite sure how to specify which folder I want the file to be downloaded to.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try

```
curl -u user:password 'ftp://mysite/%2fusers/myfolder/myfile/raw' -o ~/Downloads/myfile.raw
```

In FTP URLs, the path is relative to the starting directory (usually your homedir). You need to specify an absolute path, and that means using `%2f` to specify `/`. This is needed because the path in `ftp:` URLs is treated as [a list of slash-separated names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.2.2), each of which is supposed to be given to a separate `CWD` command. The `%2f` is decoded *after* splitting. See [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.2.2) and [*FTP URLs*](http://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/ftpurl.html).

As for the output location, just give a path to `-o`.

---

Security suggestions:

- Don't put your password in the URL. Storing it in `~/.netrc` is not particularly secure either, but it at least is hidden from `ps -ef`.
- Your password is sent in clear text. If the server supports it, use `curl --ssl-reqd` or `curl ftps://mysite/...`
- Using SFTP (the SSH file transfer protocol) would be even better.

Comment: Worked great.  Not quite sure I fully comprehend how the %2f is used, as you're also using /, but hey it works, so I'm not gonna complain.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Josiah: It seems that the URL "path" is split by `/`, and each argument is sent with a `CWD` command: `%2fusers/myfolder` as `CWD /users`, `CWD myfolder`. See [RFC 1738](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738#section-3.2.2) on this topic.

Comment: instead of myfile/raw in the ftp URL I used myfile.raw

Answer (score 3):

```
curl -T /users/myfolder/myfile.raw -u username:password "ftp://myftpsite/path/myfile.raw"
```

I use this all the time.  It works like a charm.

Comment: Am I the first one to notice this answer is wrong? The -T parameter means "file upload", while OP asked for "file download"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
curl "ftp://user:password@myftpsite/users/myfolder/myfile.raw"
```

(If the remote file name is 'myfile.raw')

Comment: When I try that, I get the following error: "curl: (9) Server denied you to change to the given directory".  I believe that it why I needed to use the -Q "CWD" command.

Answer (score 1):

It is not cURL but commandline and works super:

If you're not bound to curl, you might want to use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) in recursive mode but restricting it to one level of recursion, try the following;

```
wget --no-verbose --no-parent --recursive --level=1\
--no-directories --user=login --password=pass ftp://ftp.myftpsite.com/
```

- `--no-parent` : Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively.
- `--level=depth` : Specify recursion maximum depth level depth. The default maximum depth is five layers.
- `--no-directories` : Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving recursively.
- `--delete-after` : can be added if you need to delete files after downloading.
- `--no-host-directories` : to download right in '.' current folder, not create directory named by domain.
- `--no-clobber` : skip downloads that would download to existing files
- `--continue` : Continue getting a partially-downloaded file for more stability
- combine with `cd` : to define the destination directory

So this sample can look like a bit more complicated:

```
cd /home/destination/folder \
&& wget --no-verbose --no-parent --recursive --level=1 \
--no-directories --no-host-directories \
--no-clobber --continue \ 
--user="login" --password="pass" ftp://ftp.myftpsite.com/
```

Feel free to use such command in crontab to automate delivery and local folder synchronization.

```
crontab -e

*/5 * * * * cd /home/destination/folder && wget --no-verbose --no-parent --recursive --level=1 --no-directories --no-host-directories --no-clobber --continue --user=login --password=pass ftp://ftp.myftpsite.com/
```

Or add the key `--delete-after` for automatic delivery of files from remote to local folder.

If you have special characters in this command (e.g. password) -- put it in a separate .sh file and configure crontab to execute .sh only. Crontab is really tricky in characters escaping.

Answer (score 0):

As yan suggests,

> curl "ftp://user:password@myftpsite/users/myfolder/myfile.raw"

should work, but some FTP servers use security policies that are not standards-compliant. In those cases, the `--ftp-method singlecwd` or `--ftp-method nocwd` option may help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not bound to curl, you might want to use [lftp](https://lftp.yar.ru/features.html) , try the following;

```
lftp ftp://ftp.some.domain.com -u login@some.domain.com,'password' -e 'set ftp:ssl-allow no; mirror --Remove-source-files --verbose /remote/directory /home/destination/folder; bye'
```

Where

- `-u` username
- `,'password'` : put your password rather in quotas
- `--Remove-source-files` : deete remove files after you downloaded them
- `--verbose` : good to see info but feel free to delete on production
- `set ftp:ssl-allow no;` : only in case if you do not need to check certificate (not ssl)